# How to Filter Record Grouped by a field in PySpark Dataframe Based on Rank and Values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Pyspark dafaframe (Spark 2.2/Python 2.7) which has multiple records for each customer received on multiple days over a period of time. Here is how the simplified version of data looks like. These are ranked in order of dates (YYYY-MM-DD) when they are received for each group. Data is guaranteed to have multiple instances of each CUST_ID.

```
CUST_ID Date_received   rank
1       2015-01-01      1
1       2021-01-12      2
1       2021-01-20      3
2       2015-01-01      1
2       2017-12-31      2
2       2021-02-15      3
3       2018-01-01      1
3       2019-07-31      2
4       2015-01-01      1
4       2021-01-01      2
4       2021-01-15      3
```

I want to split this data in 2 separate dataframes. First Dataframe should only have records fulfilling below criteria-

CUST_ID was received first time (rank 1) on 2015-01-01 and next time it was received (rank 2) on or after 2021-01-01. From above data example first Dataframe should have only these rows. This should happen for each group of CUST_ID

```
CUST_ID Date_received   rank
1       2015-01-01      1
1       2021-01-12      2
4       2015-01-01      1
4       2021-01-01      2
```

And 2nd Dataframe should have rest-

```
CUST_ID Date_received   rank
1       2021-01-20      3
2       2015-01-01      1
2       2017-12-31      2
2       2021-02-15      3
3       2018-01-01      1
3       2019-07-31      2
4       2021-01-15      3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the conditions and broadcast the conditions for each CUST_ID:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df0 = df.withColumn(
    'flag1',
    (F.col('rank') == 1) & (F.col('Date_received') == '2015-01-01')
).withColumn(
    'flag2',
    (F.col('rank') == 2) & (F.col('Date_received') >= '2021-01-01')
).withColumn(
    'grp',
    F.max('flag1').over(Window.partitionBy('CUST_ID')) & 
    F.max('flag2').over(Window.partitionBy('CUST_ID'))
)

df0.show()
+-------+-------------+----+-----+-----+-----+
|CUST_ID|Date_received|rank|flag1|flag2|  grp|
+-------+-------------+----+-----+-----+-----+
|      3|   2018-01-01|   1|false|false|false|
|      3|   2019-07-31|   2|false|false|false|
|      1|   2015-01-01|   1| true|false| true|
|      1|   2021-01-12|   2|false| true| true|
|      1|   2021-01-20|   3|false|false| true|
|      4|   2015-01-01|   1| true|false| true|
|      4|   2021-01-01|   2|false| true| true|
|      4|   2021-01-15|   3|false|false| true|
|      2|   2015-01-01|   1| true|false|false|
|      2|   2017-12-31|   2|false|false|false|
|      2|   2021-02-15|   3|false|false|false|
+-------+-------------+----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Then you can divide the dataframe using the `grp` column:

```
df1 = df0.filter('grp and rank <= 2').select(df.columns)
df2 = df0.filter('not (grp and rank <= 2)').select(df.columns)

df1.show()
+-------+-------------+----+
|CUST_ID|Date_received|rank|
+-------+-------------+----+
|      1|   2015-01-01|   1|
|      1|   2021-01-12|   2|
|      4|   2015-01-01|   1|
|      4|   2021-01-01|   2|
+-------+-------------+----+

df2.show()
+-------+-------------+----+
|CUST_ID|Date_received|rank|
+-------+-------------+----+
|      3|   2018-01-01|   1|
|      3|   2019-07-31|   2|
|      1|   2021-01-20|   3|
|      4|   2021-01-15|   3|
|      2|   2015-01-01|   1|
|      2|   2017-12-31|   2|
|      2|   2021-02-15|   3|
+-------+-------------+----+
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, it solved my problem. This is interesting. Just curious, what does max('flag1') and max('flag2') yield on "ture/false"?

Comment: @Sidd max would give true if any flag in the partition is true, otherwise it will be false.